# Previously booked holiday

Tags: interviewing, vacation, telecommute

So I'm in the last stages of the interview process, they're sending me an offer, and the job I'm at right now was remote. Because of this, I had booked a flight to Italy (return flight pending) because I could work remotely from there (boss at current company knows this, and it's common to do), now the new job is not remote.

I'm wondering how I can approach the subject? I was thinking of laying it out plain and simple when I get an offer and just saying I have a trip booked already, but that I'd be open to either having it be unpaid time off, or working remote from there (particularly since I've proven I can work remotely). Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Whatever money you paid for the Italy flight, is a write-off.  If you can refund the ticket, great.  If not, it's just a loss.  Mistakes happen in life, forget about - it's only a few hundred bucks.

Comment: Disagree with @Fattie's statement.  If you have a time off accommodation needed because you locked in expenses before ever interviewing with this company, they'll usually find a way to accommodate.  The larger problem is you not mentioning it earlier. Even if you held onto this until later in the process, they should have known about it before putting together their offer.

Comment: @Fattie Not at all.  I've had booked vacation during multiple new jobs.  You tell them in the interview process, and everything is fine.  Its not an uncommon situation, and if they're willing to spend the money/time to invest in hiring you, they're willing to give you a week or two off.  The only thing that may be a problem is the open ended return date, telling them its a 2 week trip would work better.

Comment: for sure, but the OP _didn't tell them_.  He only wants to tell them now.

Answer (score 4):

You should have brought it up when they asked "when are you available?" Now you're basically blindsiding them.

**Let them know immediately.  As in right now**. If I were the one doing the hiring, this would severely annoy me and if I had an equally qualified candidate, would would make the offer to them instead. If I didn't, it would certainly start things off on a bad foot.

Give them the time to decide before they actually make the offer. Whatever you told them is your availability is what they will rightfully expect when they make the offer.  They need to know ASAP that it isn't what they were told initially.

Comment: @christopher, they did ask when are you available, but from what I had read online they kept saying to wait until you have an offer to ask them about previously booked vacations. I think at this point I might write it off as a loss because the job is a very good career step and I'd rather not risk it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something where it's much later than the projected start date, just let them know that you already paid for tickets for a planned trip on such and such a date, and that you will need to be able to take that time off.

If there's some kind of limitation on when you can take the time, or whether you've earned that time, then you need to negotiate having that paid time available and being able to use it.

Most companies will find a way to make it work for a new hire.